# Using smallest necessary C type vs just using int

Tags: c, c11, abi, integer-promotion

Given a C function (random example):

```
void* getMyStuff( size_t size, unsigned char alignment );
```

Does using `unsigned char` help the compiler by telling it the limit of the values being passed, or does it hinder the compiler by preventing it from using the native `int` (or `unsigned int`) size?

I know historically it's not ideal to use `short` since 16-bit operations were not native. I don't know if that applies here (or to local variables in general).

Basically, if you are passing values smaller than 32-bit, that could fit in a smaller data type, does the compiler care which you choose?

For reference, I'm using GCC and Clang, compiling C11 (not C++11) code. This question may be ABI-specific, but I don't know how to determine that.

Edit: I'm developing on x86_64, if it matters. I would hope the answer doesn't vary among CPU vendors.

Comment: Use `int` unless there is a very good reason not to.

Comment: Depends on underline CPU.

Comment: It all boils down to the environment you're working in, and the requirements. If you have speed or size requirements, using native types probably help. If you have quality requirements, using defined types (including smallest necessary size) help find errors. If you have both, or if you have none, it's up to you and your team. -- Anyway, this is commonly opinion-based, so I'm afraid your question will be closed soon.

Comment: How is this opinion based? I'm wanting to know what the compiler will do with my code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Does using unsigned char help the compiler by telling it the limit of the values being passed, or does it hinder the compiler by preventing it from using the native int (or unsigned int) size?

Depends on the CPU and ABI. Whatever is most efficient depends entirely on which calling conventions that are documented as fastest by the ABI.

Generally, upper-end CPUs like to work with the type of their preferred data width and alignment. 32 bit for 32 bit CPUs and so on. They may however support operations on smaller types. Lower-end CPUs (8 or 16 bit) don't like larger types at all and generally prefer to work with 8 bit types if possible.

> I know historically it's not ideal to use short since 16-bit operations were not native.

Not native *where*? 16 bit operations are perfectly "native" on all 16 bit CPUs. They may not be ideal on some 32 bitters with poor instruction support for 16 bit data.

> Basically, if you are passing values smaller than 32-bit, that could fit in a smaller data type, does the compiler care which you choose?

The compiler is generally not allowed to swap out the type you chose for a larger one, since that could change the meaning and behavior of the program. With the exception of `uint_fast8_t` and similar modern types, where the compiler is allowed to swap for a larger type if it leads to faster code.

> For reference, I'm using GCC and Clang

The compiler doesn't matter. Only the specific target port and its ABI matters. Though on some low end CPUs like specialized microcontrollers, there's generally no standardized ABI and each compiler therefore invents its own ABI/calling conventions for that target.

Comment: Thanks. I've updated my post to mention that I'm using modern x86 64-bit CPUs. Though I find it strange that the compiler wouldn't be allowed to promote a function parameter to a larger more native size.

Comment: @Nairou It may do that, as long as it can determine that it doesn't change the behavior of the program. Which might not be a trivial thing. Suppose I've written code relying on unsigned wrap-around, for example. Or code relying on certain implicit type promotions to take place. For example something ugly but valid like `~my_unsigned_char >> 8`. This relies on implicit promotion and then implementaion-defined right shift. If the compiler goes ahead to swap out my unsigned char variable for an unsigned int, it will break the program.

Answer (score 3):

The simple answer, as @WeatherVane already said in a comment, is:

Use `int` unless there is a very good reason not to.

I'm not going to make this answer longer with a bunch of painfully-rehashed arguments: everything has been said before, many times.  Not much will usually go wrong if you use `char` or `short` for parameter types, but really, there's nothing to be gained, either.  You'll probably spend more time worrying about it than you'll ever recoup in any other way.

As Andrew reminded me in a comment, the choice between `int` and `unsigned int` *is* important; I'm not trying to suggest ignoring that distinction.

Comment: But please specify `signed` or `unsigned` - it does matter

Comment: @Andrew You're right, good point.  Answer updated.

Comment: "Not much will usually go wrong if you use char ..." --> for non-text applications, using `char` adds complexity as it may be _signed_ or _unsigned_.

Comment: Since OP's specific example is about an alignment param, maybe use `size_t` instead for consistency with `_Alignof`'s type (just my opinion)? But yeah, generally `int`/`unsigned` will do just fine for most situations.

Comment: Agree with @chux-ReinstateMonica - for characters, plain `char` is fine... but plain `char` should not be used as a integer-type.